# MySQL event: Remove time-series data without change

Tags: mysql, optimization, time-series

I'm logging boiler state, means if boiler is heating or not. My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `boiler` (
  `tstamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status_code` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Every 5 minutes cron reads boiler status code and saves it into table. Data looks like this:

```
+---------------------+-------------+
| tstamp              | status_code |
+---------------------+-------------+
| 2015-02-16 01:30:02 |           0 |
| 2015-02-16 01:35:02 |           0 |
| 2015-02-16 01:40:02 |           1 |
| 2015-02-16 01:45:02 |           1 |
| 2015-02-16 01:50:02 |           1 |
| 2015-02-16 01:55:02 |           1 |
| 2015-02-16 02:00:02 |           1 |
| 2015-02-16 02:05:02 |           1 |
| 2015-02-16 02:10:02 |           1 |
| 2015-02-16 02:15:02 |           1 |
| 2015-02-16 02:20:02 |           0 |
| 2015-02-16 02:25:02 |           0 |
| 2015-02-16 02:30:02 |           0 |
| 2015-02-16 02:35:02 |           0 |
+---------------------+-------------+
```

Now, I want to optimize this data, maybe with events. I would like to remove data without change, after event run, data should looks like this:

```
+---------------------+-------------+
| tstamp              | status_code |
+---------------------+-------------+
| 2015-02-16 01:30:02 |           0 |
| 2015-02-16 01:40:02 |           1 |
| 2015-02-16 02:20:02 |           0 |
+---------------------+-------------+
```

Is it possible to write this event?

THANKS!

Comment: would seem much easier to have it done by a script that's run by cron to check the boiler status, just select last one and if the code is the same just do nothing?

Comment: Yes, maybe... But this is one more request for database every five minute. I know, that this is not much, but one event every midnight looked better for me. I'm calling this solution "backup plan" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit complicated, but you can do it with a `join` in the `delete`.  A `select` that gets the data you want is not so complicated:

```
select b.*,
       (select b2.status_code
        from boiler b2
        where b2.tstamp < b.tstamp
        order by b2.tstamp desc
        limit 1
       ) as prev_status_code
from boiler b
having prev_status_code is null or prev_status_code <> status_code;
```

The next step is to put this logic into `delete`:

```
delete b
    from boiler b join
         (select b.*,
                 (select b2.status_code
                  from boiler b2
                  where b2.tstamp < b.tstamp
                  order by b2.tstamp desc
                  limit 1
                 ) as prev_status_code
         from boiler b
        ) b2
        on b.tstamp = b2.tstamp
    where b2.prev_status_code = b2.status_code;
```

The `where` logic is reversed.  In the first case you get the rows you want to *keep*.  The second is for the rows to *delete*.

Comment: Probably should have named `prev_tstamp` `prev_scode` because in your outer WHERE clause, you accidentally compared that column with the time stamp instead of the status code. Other than that, looks good.

Comment: @MarcusAdams . . . Yes, yes, yes.  Thank you.  The logic is around the status code, not the timestamp.